# Python 2.7 MySQL-python Link Error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pip, lnk2001

I know that this has been asked a few times on here, but I have tried every solution given on each question this was asked. I've been trying to solve this for about 5 hours now, I even went to the extent of reinstalling windows to hope it magically would fix it. With that being said:

I'm running windows 10 64bit and using Python 2.7. I'm trying to do 'pip install MySQL-python' and I keep getting this:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup  
fatal error LNK1120: 56 unresolved externals  
error: command '"C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe"' failed with exit status 1120
```

Here is my entire CMD:

[image: cmd listing 1]

[image: cmd listing 2]

I apologize if any of the formatting is wrong here, I don't post much.